# Almost periodicity of Bessel functions

Tags: bessel-functions, periodic-functions, almost-periodic-function

We know that a periodic function (e.g. a trigonometric function) has the property

$$
f(x+n\Lambda)=f(x) \qquad n\in\mathbb Z
$$

A Bessel function is not exactly periodic, because the value of the function roughly decreases after each oscillation. However, one could say that is not very far from being periodic. I would like to know if it is possible to express this almost periodicity of Bessel functions, generalizing the above formula.

Would it be possible to expand such an almost periodic function in a generalized Fourier series?

More in detail, is it legitimate to write the following relation?

$$
J_{0}(kz)\sim\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}\varphi_m e^{i\lambda_mz}
$$

where the approximated expansion holds in an interval centered around $z=0$ and extends for a *few quasi-periods*.

If so, how is $\lambda_m$ calculated?

Comment: how would that equation make sense, since the right-hand-side is periodic, while the left-hand-side is not?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker since I suspect that Bessel functions are almost-periodic, I would be satisfied even with an approximated relation.

Comment: $J_{1/2}$ is a trigonometric function.  But (as you note) $J_0$ decays to $0$, so it is not of the form you wrote.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar is any expansion in discrete "frequencies" possible, for a Bessel function? Even if it is not exactly a Fourier series.

Comment: Almost periodic function cannot tend to zero as $x\to\infty$. The series you wrote never tends to zero as $z\to\infty$ on the real line. And Bessel functions do.

Comment: I think this question could make sense in the following way. Is there an almost periodic function that asymptotically approximates $x^{1/2} J_0(x)$ with better error than $O(1/x)$, which is already accomplished by $(\sin x + \cos x)/\sqrt{\pi}$? If not, could this error be improved on some interval that doesn't extend all the way to infinity, but still gets asymptotically large?

Comment: I want to thank both and @IgorKhavkine and Alexandre Eremenko for their very useful comments. Indeed, the generalized Fourier series I am looking for does not need to represent the function $J_0(x)$ over all $\mathbb R$. It is enough that the series approximates well the Bessel function in an interval centered around $x=0$ (let's say for a few "quasi-periods").

Comment: Alessandro, do you need this interval to be "large" in any way? If not, fix your favorite interval, then compute the usual Fourier series on that interval.

Comment: It would be helpful if, in the body of the question, you explain which notion of "almost periodic function" you are hoping to use. There are several variants in the literature, but my impression is that they all exclude non-zero $C_0$ functions as remarked by @AlexandreEremenko

Comment: @Alessandro Zunino: On any finite interval, you can approximate any reasonable function by a partial sum of its Fourier series. Or a series of exponentials provided that they are complete on this interval.

Comment: Functions vanishing at infinity fall into the class of null weakly almsot periodic functions. These are exactly the weakly almost periodic functions with vanishing Fourier--Bohr coefficients. In particular, in the sense of Besicovitch or Weyl almsot periodicity, they are the same as the 0 function. So Besicovitch or Weyl almost periodicity will definitely NOT give you the coefficients.   @YemonChoi

Answer (score 4):

Maple gave me this...
$$
J_0(x) = \left( {\frac {\sin \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {\pi}}}+{\frac {\cos
 \left( x \right) }{\sqrt {\pi}}} \right) x^{-1/2}+ \left( -{\frac {\cos \left( x \right) }{8\sqrt {\pi}}}+{\frac {\sin
 \left( x \right) }{8\sqrt {\pi}}} \right)  x^{-3/2}
\\+ \left( -{\frac {9\,\sin \left( x \right) }{128\,\sqrt {\pi}}}-{
\frac {9\,\cos \left( x \right) }{128\,\sqrt {\pi}}} \right)  x^{-5/2}+ \left( {\frac {75\,\cos \left( x \right) }{
1024\,\sqrt {\pi}}}-{\frac {75\,\sin \left( x \right) }{1024\,\sqrt {
\pi}}} \right)  x^{-7/2}
\\+ \left( {\frac {3675\,
\sin \left( x \right) }{32768\,\sqrt {\pi}}}+{\frac {3675\,\cos
 \left( x \right) }{32768\,\sqrt {\pi}}} \right)  x^{-9/2}
\\+ \left( -{\frac {59535\,\cos \left( x \right) }{262144
\,\sqrt {\pi}}}+{\frac {59535\,\sin \left( x \right) }{262144\,\sqrt {
\pi}}} \right)  x^{-11/2}+o(x^{-11/2})
$$
as $x \to \infty$

Comment: Thank you very much. Your Maple result looks nice, but I am looking for something like a Generalized Fourier series, as those of Besicovitch almost periodic functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function#Besicovitch_almost_periodic_functions). The multiplication term $x^{-1/2-n}$ looks like a big departure from an expansion in "discrete frequencies".

Comment: @AlessandroZunino Besicovitch AP seems to be a red herring if you merely want an approximation in some interval around $x=0$. As pointed out above, AP functions _in the sense of Bohr_ cannot tend to zero at infinity, and I think the same also applies to the Besicovitch $B_p$-spaces